# Error rest_post_invalid_page_number trying to call Rest API

Tags: rest-api

I got the following error, trying to call all posts or alle posts from a specific post type via the REST API:

`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`
`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1`
`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=1`
`/wp-json/wp/v2/faq`

The error which appears is:

> {
>           "code": "rest_post_invalid_page_number",
>           "message": "The page number requested is larger than the number of pages available.",
>           "data": {
>               "status": 400
>           }
>       }

I got two posts within the custom post type and one normal post.

What causes this error?

Comment: What's your code? And you should use `per_page` to limit the number of posts, like so: `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3` - [demo](http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3). That's for the standard post type, but should also work for custom post types.

Comment: I have no code written yet. I am just trying to get the result within the browser.

Comment: Ok, but the error actually clearly suggests that there were no posts found for the request. Are you 100% sure the normal post you have is not private (and published)? If yes, then there's probably a plugin or custom code which filters the REST API response and excluding that post.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that there are published posts. :/

Comment: The only plugin activated is AdvancedCustomFieldsPro

Comment: Just try disabling that plugin? And try a default theme.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why yet, but I had the same issue until I disabled a filter on `pre_get_posts`.

What I'm doing here is retrieve all `recipe` custom post type when I'm on the home page :

```
// add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query )
{
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'recipe' ) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );

    return $query;
}
```

Try to know if you're hijacking a main query like I did, I'll do more research on the "why" :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same above issue. I disabled the 'pre_get_posts and it worked fine.

// add_action('pre_get_posts','pre_queries');

Comment: Where's that from? That's not a default WordPress-core-supplied hook I don't think.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).